# Why the state function of Internal Energy $U$ can be defined as $U(T,V)$?

Tags: thermodynamics

We can define $du$ as $du = đq + đw$.

Can we define the state function of $U$ be $U(q,w)$? Why the state function is defined as $U(T,V)$?

Answer (score 3):

1. The answer to your first question is no: $U$ is a state function, while work and heat are not; that is, they depend on the path taken. This is also the reason that we write them with a bar on the  $d$. Because they are not exact differentials, you cannot write $U = U(Q,W)$.

   In fact, $U(1,3)$ and $U(4,5)$ and so on in that case might show the same
   point!!
2. However, you can write $U$ in terms of other (in your case, two) independent variables that describe the state of your system uniquely. For an ideal gas, for example, you need only two "coordinates" to completely describe the state of the gas. You can choose them as $(P,V)$ or $(P,T)$  or $(T,V)$ or ...; usually, in the case of an reversible process, the first law is written in this form:  $dU = TdS - PdV$ (for a hydrostatic system). Here, $U$ is now a function of $S$ and $V$, but you can write it to use the other terms by applying a Legendre transformation.
3. If you're new to this stuff, I highly recommend you take a look at the first chapter of [*Heat and Thermodynamics - Zemansky & Dittman (7th edition)*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070170592)
   (also a good textbook if you want to read more).

Edit : The first law in the form you wrote is just the conservation of energy therefore it's always correct but you should be careful in your interpretations of it , the other form $dU = TdS-PdV$ is for a reversible process (closed , hydrostatic system) and it is not limited to ideal gases at all! you can take a look at this [wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_thermodynamic_relation) it has a good derivation of this form in it , also take a look at chapter 3 (first 5 pages) of [Equilibrium Thermodynamics - Adkins](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521274567) it has really good and semi-historical discussion about the first law ,I hope that helps.

Comment: But usually V and T are nice variable that are more easily measured comapred to e.g. entropy ,S.

Comment: Hi @Kia.J, for future reference, [this MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/812243) may be useful for writing formulas. Also, instead of posting a comment, you can always [edit the answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/editing) if you want to add more information.

Comment: @Urb , Thank you very much , I will surely do .

Comment: Thanks! You mentioned that for an ideal gas, two independent variables are sufficient to describe the state of the system. Then since $U(S,V)$, does the first law only applies to ideal gas? (I am very new to this topic. Sorry if I ask sth silly).